# Uploading 2 iOS apps in Appstore for one app release?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

Can I have 2 iOS apps uploaded in Apple Appstore, so that I can launch one app from another internally for some functionality and vice versa. For ex: App A and App B. For doing some functionality, I want to launch App B from App A. In this case, I should have both apps on the device, so that i can launch like this using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myAppBURL];`. So, Can I have these 2 apps in Appstore, so that users can download both and having that particular feature also working?

Any suggestions please?

Comment: It sounds like what you're describing is what Facebook does with their FB Messenger app.  Each is available on the App Store, but when you tap "Messages" in Facebook, it automatically opens the Messenger app.  Is that what you're aiming to do?

Comment: Yes, in my case it is different. App B will have only one functionality, it should be used launching from App A only. If user directly launching App B on the device, then it is a problem, it should not work. In case of FB, two apps have different functionalities, so it can be opened separately also. But, In my case, second app can be hidden on the device, it depends on the App A to launch. How can i handle it? Can i hide one app - App B ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the app store

Comment: I'm about 1,000% sure that Apple won't let you put an app on the App Store that you can't launch natively.  If you HAVE to launch it from the other app, it will get rejected from the App Store.  You'll either need to allow it to open on its own, or integrate App B into App A as a single app.

Comment: So, I can conclude that, If I have two apps, both two apps should have some specific functionality and able to launch and work separately. In this case, for some reason, If App A wants to launch App B, then it is acceptable to launch like this.

Comment: Why in the Appstore guidelines it is mentioned like this? -> Apps that install or launch other executable code will be rejected

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store policy, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701)

Comment: This is NOT appstore specific question. This is clearly explaining about launching one app from another programmatically. It should be approved here.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to clarify this:
If you have two apps, both should be able to exist independently: specific functionality, independent launch etc.
The need for independence between apps is, at the same time, compatible with app inter-communication.
You can call app B from app A and supply a custom URL so that you send B a specific message.

In the question you ask in the comments, the answer is: you cannot run code from the outside of Apple ecosystem. But of course you may launch Safari, or app B if it has been approved. In fact, what you are doing is again communicating, not executing anything nor downloading code.